# TYPO3 7.6 link a file with typoscript typolink and target?

Tags: typo3, typolink

has someone also this problem:
I have a Typoscript Code which generate a Link to a Fileressource. If I add a `target = _blank` nothing change in frontend. If i Link a page `target = _blank` is working.

So I think my Typoscript is fine, im able to link to the file. And if I link to a page `target = _blank` is working.
But it seems not possible to have a typolink to a fileressource with `target = _blank`. I had also tried extTarget and nothing happened.

```
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.value = || DOWNLOAD || LOW 

    renderObj.value.typolink.parameter.data=file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
    renderObj.value.typolink.parameter.wrap = file:|

    # this is working:
    # renderObj.value.typolink.parameter=4

    renderObj.value.typolink.target = _blank
    renderObj.value.typolink.ATagParams = || class="download_high" || class="download_low"
```

Comment: I found my failure, for file links the Typoscript path have to bei fileTarget. 
This is the final solution:
renderObj.value.typolink.fileTarget = _blank

Answer (score 1):

I did'nt know the target parameter for the typolink object. I do blank links always this style:

```
lib.logo = IMAGE
lib.logo {
  file = EXT:theme/Resources/Public/img/logo.jpg
  file {
    height = 43
  }
  stdWrap.typolink.parameter = 1 _blank
}
```

This generates a link on a page with uid and _blank for new window. Maybe you can add it to your wrap like

```
renderObj.value.typolink.parameter.wrap = file:| _blank
```

?

Comment: this is not working in my case. i want to build a link that point to a file. your code ist building a link around a file. appending _blank to the wrap destroys the link

Answer (score 0):

I saw you gave the solution ... AFTER I read and elaborated all, I propose your answer as answer (styled);

```
renderObj = TEXT
renderObj {
    value = || DOWNLOAD || LOW 
    typolink {
        parameter.data = file:current:originalUid // file:current:uid
        parameter.wrap = file:|
        fileTarget = _blank
        ATagParams = || class="download_high" || class="download_low"
    }
}
```